# Dynamically Set Fields of Records with Multiple Versions In SQL Update Loop

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, datetime

I am having issues working out an SQL function in Postgresql. I have managed to get this done in python but it takes a very long time on a table with millions of records.

What I have is an 'example_table' that is structured as follows with data that resembles the sample below:

#### Example Table

```
id  | version  | valid_from          | valid_to             | time_valid
1   | 1        | 2010-03-21 19:00:00 | 2010-03-21 19:00:00  | NULL
1   | 2        | 2011-02-02 09:00:00 | 2011-02-02 09:00:00  | NULL
1   | 3        | 2012-04-20 15:00:00 | 2012-04-20 15:00:00  | NULL
2   | 1        | 2012-07-02 04:00:00 | 2012-07-02 04:00:00  | NULL
3   | 1        | 2011-05-05 05:00:00 | 2011-05-05 05:00:00  | NULL`
```

As you can see I have 3 records with id "1" and each are a corresponding version (i.e, 1:3 in this case)

I would like to update the versions 2 and 1 by setting 'valid_to' equal to the 'valid_from' value in later version.

#### Updated Table

```
id | version  | valid_from             | valid_to                | time_valid
1  | 1        | 2010-03-21 19:00:00    | **2011-02-02 09:00:00** | **Some Time**
1  | 2        |**2011-02-02 09:00:00** | **2012-04-20 15:00:00** | **Some Time**
1  | 3        |**2012-04-20 15:00:00** | 2012-04-20 15:00:00     | NULL
2  | 1        |2012-07-02 04:00:00     | 2012-07-02 04:00:00     | NULL
3  | 1        |2011-05-05 05:00:00     | 2011-05-05 05:00:00     | NULL
```

Some records will have many versions while others may not have any (only one). It would also be convenient to calculate a time_valid field at the same time, which I assume is done by subtracting the valid_to and the valid_from timestamps. Again I have millions upon millions of records and multiple tables I need to this to - so faster is indeed better.

Many thanks for any working code examples!

As per request here is the python code I currently have. I have tried several modifications of this playing with limits, executemany, fetchmany, iterators...but in all cases it either ate all the local memory and crashed or was painfully slow:

```
cur.execute('''SELECT id, valid_from,valid_to, version FROM hist_line where valid_to = valid_from limit 10000;''')
for rec in cur.fetchall():
        r = 'SELECT id, valid_from, valid_to, version FROM hist_line WHERE id = %s and version = %s;' % (rec['id'],rec['version']+1)
        cur1.execute(r)
        r = cur1.fetchone()
        if r:
            out = {'id': rec['id'], 'valid_from':rec['valid_from'],'valid_to':r['valid_from'],'version':rec['version'],'time_valid':r[1]-rec[1]}
            cur1.execute('''UPDATE hist_line SET valid_to = %(valid_to)s
        WHERE id = %(id)s and version = %(version)s and valid_from = %(valid_from)s and valid_from = valid_to''', out)
```

Comment: It would be best to include any attempts you've made, even if it is the slow python code.

Comment: Sure thing - will add it now.

Comment: Have you tried performing a single, big, update instead of a loop with a select and update in it?

Comment: No that is somewhat the point of the question. I haven't been able to work out a single sql statement to do the python code above.

Comment: @user440: maybe you could change the question title to something more descriptive?

Comment: How does that one fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Lead()` and `lag()` are two of the [window-functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html). They allow you (in this case) to access the "previous" or "next" record, given a certain ordering, which you have to specify in the `OVER( ...)` or `WINDOW( ...)` clause.

```
-- the data
CREATE TABLE ExampleTable
        (id INTEGER NOT NULL
        , version INTEGER NOT NULL
        , valid_from          TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
        , valid_to              TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
        , time_valid    text
        );

INSERT INTO ExampleTable(id, version, valid_from, valid_to, time_valid) VALUES
 (1  , 1        , '2010-03-21 19:00:00' , '2010-03-21 19:00:00'  ,NULL)
,(1   , 2        , '2011-02-02 09:00:00' , '2011-02-02 09:00:00' ,NULL)
,(1   , 3        , '2012-04-20 15:00:00' , '2012-04-20 15:00:00' ,NULL)
,(2   , 1        , '2012-07-02 04:00:00' , '2012-07-02 04:00:00' ,NULL)
,(3   , 1        , '2011-05-05 05:00:00' , '2011-05-05 05:00:00' ,NULL)
        ;

-- Check what the update will do
SELECT dst.* , src.lll AS newvalue
FROM ExampleTable dst
JOIN    (
        SELECT id,version
                , lead(valid_from) OVER (partition by id ORDER BY version) lll
        FROM ExampleTable
        ) src
ON src.id = dst.id AND src.version = dst.version
WHERE src.lll IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY id,version
        ;


-- Do the update (remove the explain if it looks okay)
EXPLAIN
UPDATE ExampleTable dst
        SET valid_to = src.lll
FROM    (
        SELECT id,version
                , lead(valid_from) OVER (partition by id ORDER BY version) lll
        FROM ExampleTable
        ) src
WHERE src.id = dst.id
AND src.version = dst.version
AND src.lll IS NOT NULL
        ;


SELECT * FROM ExampleTable
ORDER BY id,version
        ;
```

Comment: Thanks, Joop. I must say this is rather dense and I had little hope of figuring it out myself (In fact I am not sure I understand it now either). Regardless, I will give it a go and let you know now.